# How to find List of objects inside list of integers

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a List of object List and ObjectA contains a parameter integer Id and I do also have a list of integers List.

I need to find all the objects whose Id contains inside list of integers.
I am trying to use Linq but can't find right query.
Tried where or find but can't come up with a good query.

```
objectALists.Where(x => x.Id.In(intIds))....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `Contains` with a `Where` clause:

```
objectList.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

If your object list is a `List<T>` you can also use [`FindAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method with a predicate:

```
objectList.FindAll(x => idList.Contains(x.Id));
```